# Is it possible in c# to get the attributes attached to a property from within the instance of that property, without knowing the containing class?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

The title is a bit of a mouthful, but it's easier to see in code:

```
public struct MyStruct {
    public bool HasAttribute(Attribute attribute) {
        //is there any way to know?
        return ??????;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    [SomeAttribute]
    MyStruct child;

    public MyClass() {}
}
```

I already know how to find the attributes on `MyClass.child` by getting the property info for each of its properties and then calling `GetCustomAttributes`, but this only works if I know that the struct instance corresponds to `MyClass.child`. What I'd like to do here is to figure out if a particular instance of a struct has attributes attached to it, without knowing what class contains the particular instance.

It would make sense to me if you couldn't do this for reference types because the instance could be referenced from multiple places, but shouldn't the set of attributes always be well-defined for value types?

My use case is making a library where the behavior of certain objects can be modified slightly by attaching custom attributes. If there's a more idiomatic way to approach this then I'm open to suggestions. I'm also willing to go into an unsafe context if that allows for a solution.

Comment: I tried to address this in my question when talking about value types vs reference types. My understanding is that a particular instance of a struct can only be referenced from one place because it's a value type. I agree that it doesn't make sense for classes.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because custom attributes were designed to extend built-in attributes like `public`, `private`, `static`. Custom attributes behave similarly to these built-in attributes, just like we cannot know whether the instance is declared as public, or private.

Comment: Thanks, that puts it in perspective. Do you think it's possible to find the scope of an object though? For code within the struct to determine that it's a property of MyClass? Maybe with reflection?

Comment: Why do you need an instance method HasAttribute to get non-instance related information? I mean, couldn't you change the implementation to something like this? HasAttribute<AttrClass>(()=>yourObj.MyStructProp)? This way you could manipulate the Expression to know if the prop has attributes attached

Comment: This would require knowing the object that contains the struct if I'm understanding you correctly. The context is a library for other people to use so it's not possible to have this information.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that's not possible. `[SomeAttribute]` is attached to the *field* of `MyClass`, and is completely unrelated to `MyStruct`.

There's no way to get the *container* of a struct for a couple of reasons:

- It could simply be a local variable or a temporary, which means the struct could either live on the stack or in a CPU register. So, no there's no containing class there.
- It could be contained in another struct, which would be subject to the same issue.
- If it's contained in a class, you'd have to retrieve the container type using only the struct's address. And that would involve very nasty code, if possible at all.

  Just imagine: The address of such a struct would be the address of its containing class plus an offset. You'd have to somehow find the address of the container's vtable (assuming you could infer what looks like a vtable just from a memory address). This would be totally hazardous/unsafe *and* unreliable, you'd run the risk of getting access violations all the time since you'd have to dereference unknown addresses. There's just *no way* to get something reliable out of it.

  Oh, and you'd also have to do this *while* the GC could potentially move your container object around, without the possibility of pinning it since you don't know its address in the first place.

A saner approach would be to use the CLR debugging API, but at this point I'll assume you just *don't want to summon Cthulhu*.

I'm sure there are many other ways to achieve what you want there, but I can't be more specific without more details. Right now, I'd suggest initializing your struct explicitly, with additional parameters:

```
public class MyClass {
    MyStruct child = new MyStruct(doThatSpecialThingie: true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! I moved away from initializing the struct directly because I need it to support assignment from other types. I set up implicit casting but, because I can't overload the assignment operator, I can't persist the value of `doThatSpecialThingie`. It's even worse because the behavior modifier is a string so I can't just create a handful of types as a workaround. I was hoping that attaching an attribute would allow me to persist some information post assignment. Is it possible to accomplish anything like this in c#?

Comment: @Ivanna well I guess you're in a typical case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here... please read that post, and then your best bet would be to post another question stating *exactly* what you need. You should link to this question to show what you've attempted, but the question should be about your requirement itself, not about the way you think it could be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hadn't heard of that before but it makes sense. I thought I was helping by trying to work towards a solution before asking but I can see the issues with that. I posted a more direct question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255918/how-can-i-persist-information-about-an-object-after-assignment-in-c